# PHP .zip download failes with 'Content-Length'

Tags: php, ssl, nginx, zip

I'm trying to start a download for a zip file from my server. The server I'm using has debian 9.2 as distribution with nginx 1.13.6 (+libressl) with an active ssl cert.

The download works with Edge and Firefox while setting `Content-Length` to the filesize but in chrome the download files with the message:

> Failed network error

```
$archiveName = $this->m_path . $this->m_file;

ob_start();

header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
// works now with chrome, but the file is corrupted
// header("Content-Length: ".filesize($this->m_path . $this->m_file));
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$archive_name."\"");
ob_flush();
ob_clean();
readfile($this->m_path . $this->m_file);
```

Without `Content-Length`, chrome can download the file but it's corrupted.

I appreciate any help from you,

regards

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you don't let nginx serve the *.zip file by itself but that you do this somehow in your code? In this case the code sending the file should be added to the question because the problem might be there.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry for that. I'm trying to download a file when it's requested by a user. The file is stored as .zip file on the server, the php script is checking if the user is valid and set the download header. Added the code to my question.

Comment: Strange. While probably not the cause of the problem: why do you set `Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary` ? There is no content-transfer-encoding for the HTTP body so this header should do nothing in the best case and in the worst case trigger some strange and unwanted behavior. Also, how exactly are the data corrupted: just too short or any bytes changed?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich : Dear sir, i removed the line and mine worked. When i gave the full path then it wasn't working but when the path like this : '../../../' then it was working...........so after seeing your answer i removed the line and it worked.....my post --------- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55652132/relative-path-issue-in-php-filesize-and-readfile/55653285#55653285

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ob_clean()` and `flush()` at the beginning and end respectively. Worked for me and also this `header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");` needs to be removed.